# Why doesn't my code change the cursor using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cursor

This is my code:

```
$('body').css('cursor','url(http://5211.91.tc/imcur/020.cur),auto');
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is a jQuery issue?  Have you tried `document.body.style.cursor = "url(http://5211.91.tc/imcur/020.cur), auto";` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html) has defined some rules for cursor images, one of them -

> The size of the image must be 32x32 pixels or lower. This is a (Windows) OS restriction; not a browser restriction.

Comment: The cursor appears fine for me in Internet Explorer if I apply the style directly.  I don't think size is the problem.

Comment: I am unable to see the cursor in Firefox 3.5.8 on Ubuntu. I defined it in CSS.